# postgresql cross join results duplication issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run a PostgreSQL query against two tables using the cross join command (not sure if this is correct?). I require all values in the landing_status columns to be returned but in separate columns as shown below in the screenshot. However, the value of each column seems to be duplicated. Is it something to do with the select * on the first line?

```
select *
from
    (select homebase.landing_status as homebase_status from homebase) homebase
cross join
    (select wickes.landing_status as wickes_status from wickes) wickes
```

See the screenshots below.

[image]

The homebase table only has 4 rows so i don't know why 16 are being presented? And the same number of rows are presented for the Wickes table. So there is some duplication

[image]

[image]

Comment: CROSS JOIN yields the Carthesian product (and 4*4 == 16)

Comment: What is the result you expect? Also: sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score -1):

The point of Cross Join is to cross between tables, So you should expect 4x4=16 rows at total. If you want to get All possible non-duplicated values you may want to use `Distinct` keyword. [This article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) can help you.

Comment: i want to display all values from the "landing_status" column from both tables but in two separate columns using the aliases specified. I don't think "distinct" will return the desired results

Comment: Please do not use w3schools (not to be confused with the [actual W3C](https://www.w3.org/)) as a good source of information, for anything, ever. Quite often the information can be out of date, wrong, and in some cases dangerous with massive backdoors. Please instead refer to more reputable or official sources of information, in the current case [here is the docs from postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html) on CROSS JOIN